# Query con select distinct y count

Tags: mysql, sql

quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar a realizar el siguiente query...

Tengo una tabla en la cual se registran muchos datos, los cuales se diferencian por 3 estados 'Bueno', 'Malo', 'Sospechoso' y en dicha tabla pueden agregar desde solo 1 dato hasta 100 al mismo tiempo con la diferencia de estado, pueden haber 30 'Bueno' pero con diferencia de ingreso 10 pudieron haberse ingresado a las 12:00 y otras 10 a la 1:30

por ejemplo en la siguiente imagen de como tengo unos datos de prueba
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede notar, la diferencia de ingreso es muy poca.

La intencion de mi query es para hacer una tabla con chartjs y mostrar la cantidad de buenas, malas o sospechosas con referencia de hora.

Comment: Recuerda que es muy importante aportes un  [mcve], te recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta es como realizar el query o como impementar chartjs?

Comment: @JuanRivera sobre como hacer el query ahorita intente hacer uno pero no functiono algo asi `` SELECT COUNT(*) AS todo FROM (SELECT DISTINCT created_at FROM capturepiece);``

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega la consulta sql que escribiste en tu comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

Muestra el total de registros por fecha, hora y estado.

```
SELECT DATE(created_at), HOUR(created_at), estado, count(*)
FROM capturepiece
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), HOUR(created_at), estado
ORDER BY DATE(created_at), HOUR(created_at), estado;
```

Si quieres excluir las filas que tiene la misma fecha y hora de creación, y estado puedes hacerla así:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at), HOUR(created_at), estado, count(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT created_at, estado FROM capturepiece) AS aux
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), HOUR(created_at), estado
ORDER BY DATE(created_at), HOUR(created_at), estado;
```

Comment: es lo que ecestaba!! muchas gracias. de puuura casualidad, sabras como implementarlo en eloquent?

Comment: De nada @cesg.dav! No, nunca lo he usado.